# What does a 1d6/1d6 damage mean?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, weapons, double-weapons

When reading the weapon attacks from the core rulebook I noticed quarterstaves (and a few other weapons) have something like this under the Dmg column;

1d6/1d6

What does this mean? It looks to me like a second attack, but I thought you could attack twice with ANY weapon if you have enough BAB. Is that not the case? do you need a second weapon or a double attack weapon to attack twice with enough BAB?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It means it's a [Double Weapon](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons#wpn-quality-double)

> You can use a double weapon to fight as if fighting with two weapons,
>   but if you do, you incur all the normal attack penalties associated
>   with fighting with two weapons, just as if you were using a one-handed
>   weapon and a light weapon. You can choose to wield one end of a double
>   weapon two-handed, but it cannot be used as a double weapon when
>   wielded in this way—only one end of the weapon can be used in any
>   given round.

So you can use one end of the weapon, or both. The damage rolls there are for each of the two ends of the weapon.

Comment: Oh, I see!  So it doesn't grant me a second attack, but if I had a second attack due to BAB then I could use both ends in 1 round?

Comment: It does grant you a second attack, if you use it like two weapons and use two weapon fighting. If you do, the penalties for two weapon fighting apply. Or you can use it like one weapon and get the extra attacks with BAB. Or both. This weapon just had the option of being one or two weapons at the same time, which is your choice at the time you attack.

Comment: The reason that it's noted this way is because [some weapons have different damage for each end](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons/weapon-descriptions/hammer-gnome-hooked).

Answer (score 3):

It means it is a double weapon, that let's you attack twice in a round even if you don't have enough BAB to get a second attack, suffering the Two-Weapon Fighting penalities.

[See this paragraph on the SRD ^^](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Two-Weapon-Fighting)